# Clear fopensock stream buffer/history in PHP for Asterisk

Tags: php, asterisk

I am connecting to Asterisk via PHP using fopensock() and then read and write to the/from the CLI using fputs() and fget(), e.g:

```
$socket = fopensock('127.0.0.1',port, $errno, $errstr, 1); //connect
fputs($socket,"Action: Login\r\nUserName: mark\r\nSecret: test\r\n\r\n"); //login
fputs($socket,"Action: Command\r\nCommand: core show channel $channel\r\n\r\n"); //command
$line = fgets($socket); //read output
```

This works fine, however I cannot figure out how to clear the stream buffer/history without logging out and logging back in each time I issue a new command.

I tried `fflush($socket)` but this does not seem to have any effect.

When I tried `truncate($socket,ftell($socket))` I get error `Can't truncate this stream!`

Answer (score 0):

IF you need flush read stream, simplest way is just read without blocking until you have info.

You can't remove info from write script once it sent.